# Why can't I install compiz-plugins-extra?

Tags: compiz

I have installed Ubuntu 13.10, but I can't add compiz-plugins-extra, a collection of extra plugins from OpenCompositing for Compiz. I tried running the command `sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager compiz-plugins-extra`, but it says the most recent version is already installed. Does anybody know what should be done in such a case?

Answer (score 0):

If it tells you that "recent version is already installed" is because it's already installed. There were a bunch of plugins removed from the packages that were deemed as unstable, those you will not find them for the normal channels for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 0):

had the same problem I ran `sudo apt-get update` 
to install the recent updates.
Then `sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager compiz-plugins-extra`
Worked like a charm,